# Creating a customized Exception class

Tags: java, oop, exception

I am creating a customized Exception class that extends IllegalArgument. When I call on it, to catch in the program, it doesn't work. Can someone please help and tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
public class IllegalTemperatureException extends IllegalArgumentException {
    public IllegalTemperatureException() {
        super("Invalid Temperature!");
    }
}
```

Comment: What's wrong? What is the error?

Comment: Please show us how you try to use this. Please show the error message. Please try to ask as complete a question as possible. The [help] section can help you with this.

Comment: Show us the code where you use it.

Comment: .... any time you're ready.

Comment: sorry guys, forgot to respond. Will be more attentive on my next question.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class MyExceptionClass extends Exception{

    public MyExceptionClass() {
        super("Invalid Temperature!");
    }

}
```

In your code you can throw the exception like this:
...

```
public void myMethod() throws MyExceptionClass{

    MyExceptionClass e = new MyExceptionClass();
    throw e;
}
```

Comment: Also - the "e" in the declaration is an error. Delete it. And it should say "public" and not "Public".